# I want to make a HD picture as my responsive background

Tags: html, css

so I want to make an image(2988 x 2988) as my background I tried this code as my css

```
   body {
   background-image: url(images/nicholas-kwok-225380-unsplash.jpg);
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-color:#464646;
  }
```

and please look at the picture to understand what I am talking about guys

[image: picture one]

[image: Picture two the problem]

Thank you !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `image(2988 x 2988) as my background` Jeeez;  this is going to really suck for someone on mobile data and with only a 480px wide screen.

Comment: I bet your server doesn't even deliver site contents compressed, either. hah

Comment: Haha ,, i will try to change the resolution of the picture :3 ..

Comment: @Martin, do you have any idea what you're talking about? Can you even guess how well a BW photo can be compressed?

Comment: @Shomz enlighten me

Comment: @PeterB sorry I'am late , But the question is how to make the background image fit the screen without getting bigger or shrinking ! I want it to be as a full fixed background ,, But I want to ask does the size of the picture matters to make that happen ?!

Comment: @Martin OK, here goes the enlightenment: the black/white PNG of that size can easily go under 100KB (even less, depending on the image) - the server compression is almost irrelevant compared to the actual image compression. If you're unhappy with all the lost/unseen pixels on small devices, srcsets, media queries or SVGs can cover that easily.

Comment: @ZakariaTouati Do you want to keep the aspect ratio or you just want it to fill the whole space?

Comment: @shomz , I want it to fill the whole space (screen) !

Comment: @ZakariaTouati Okay, it's a simple background size fix, wrote you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you want to keep the aspect ratio or you just want it to fill the whole space?

---

> @shomz , I want it to fill the whole space (screen) !

---

Based on the comment above, a simple:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

should do. This will always stretch the image to fill your screen.

See here:

```css
body {
   background-image: url(https://www.picpng.com/images/large/hat-male-man-person-silhouette-transparent-95008);
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-color:#464646;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
   background-image: url('images/nicholas-kwok-225380-unsplash.jpg');
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-color:#464646;
   margin:0;           /* 1 */
   width:100%;         /* 2 */
   min-height:100vh;   /* 3 */
   height:auto;        /* 4 */
}
```

**1:** As described in comments the `Body` HTML element often has a default margin value (`0.5rem`) which means it can't naturally cover the screen size entirely.

**2:** Set the image to scale to the size of the body.

**3:** Set the body to be a *minimum* height of the entire screen viewport height. So if the body contents is less than the screen size you still see the full body background image.

**4:** A fix for some browsers (`IE / Edge`) that will not accept `min-height` values being set without a `height` value also being set.

---

As a significant but side issue: your image size (2988px x 2988px) is **HUGE** and deeply impractical for 95% of your website viewers. You should either consider reducing your image size to something more usual (~1800px) and/or using some sort of image optimisation tool to radically reduce the filesize.

Image files will need to be downloaded by the client so a ~400Kb image (for example) loading on a ~12Kb webpage will be a big burden for your server to serve and will be slow for the client browser to get and load into memory.

I would recommend reducing the image pixel dimensions *and* running it [through an optimiser tool](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/) .

***OR***

You should use media queries in the CSS so that you only need to load the largest image for the current client screen width. A user on a 480px screen has no need for a 2988px width image.

IF you load a very large image into a small screen space, the browser will firstly download the whole image (wasting above 90% of the data) and will then badly/quickly rescale the image to fit the screen -- making it look worse than it actually is by using a fast but imprecise scaling algorithm.

---

**Update:**

To show the ***full*** picture in the background regardless of screen size, you want to change `cover` to `contain` thus:

```
 background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer , I really appreciate the help .. but the problem is not solved :( ! the width of the picture is fine , but height is not ,, I dont know what to do now :/ but i think the problem is from the pictures (HD ones taken from Unsplash) ..

Comment: It may be the size ratio; do you want the picture to `Fill` the space or do you want the `Whole` picture to be seen in the background?

Comment: @ZakariaTouati to do the first: `cover` to do the second: `contain` in the CSS .